# ArcGIS Pro not loading associated world file with .PNG raster

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, imagery, world-file

I am fairly new to GIS, and brand new to ArcGIS Pro (came from ArcMap).

I recently created a visual basic program that generates an image from the Google Static Maps API with a respective ESRI world file (.PGW).  Below is an example image with the corresponding [world file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file):

[image: staticmap.png]

```
0.000171661 
0
0
-0.00012673
-122.8704705 
42.4147755
```

The image is named "staticmap.png" and the world file is "staticmap.pgw", they are both saved in the same folder.  Here are some of the things I've tried so far:

- Loading it in without the world file present, it loads in the Pacific Ocean.
- Assigning the Mercador Web Map and then loading the image with world file in my map, which results in it appearing outside of Africa (it should be in southern oregon).
- Deleting all references to the image / world file in ArcGIS Pro and regenerating both, loading into my map without a projection (It loads in the same spot it loaded without a world file present).  This step convinced me that the program is ignoring my world file for some reason, maybe I wrote it incorrectly?
- Tried it in ArcMap with the same results.

Comment: What spatial reference are you assigning to the layer?

Comment: According to Googles support page for the Static Maps API their imagery uses the WGS 1984 Web Mercador projection, I am using that as the spatial reference.

Comment: Did you try replacing the -122 and 42 in the pgw with their web mercator coordinates for that location?

Comment: Ah you might be onto something here, I just used the Lat Long coordinates from points on google maps.  Let me check and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGIS IS reading your pgw file. Your file points the x1, y1 point (the two last numbers in your pgw file) to -122.8704705, 42.4147755, which is in Web Mercator, near Africa. When it should be pointing to something like -13396443.965, 5568945.439 (coordinates near Oregon).

Comment: Thank you for this!  Those coordinates I am using are the Lat Long values from Google Maps, are they GPS units?  Sorry I am a complete novice with coordinates and transformations.

Comment: Yes, when I open your file in geographic coordinate system, the image appears in Medford. Geographic coordinates systems use degrees as units, the Web Mercator is a projected coordinate system and uses meters as units.

Comment: Be careful to not just change coordinates because the cell values will be still wrong. Use ArcToolbox->Data Management Tools->Projections and Transformations->Raster->Project Raster and set the gcs initial projection and the Webmercator output projection (search for 3857 epsg). I could reproject it changing extension to tif. The tfw should be like this: 22.2355311179
0.0000000000
0.0000000000
-16.4137715288
-13677876.6464319360
5223316.0736071728