# ArcGIS Pro not reading PGW file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, png

When I upload the PNG file into ArcGIS Pro it doesn't seem to access or read the associated PGW file. The error I get is that it has "Unknown Coordinate System"

How do I go about correcting the unknown coordinate system or get it to read the PGW file?

Comment: A world file doesn't provide a coordinate system, just the orientation and scaling parameters. "Unknown coordinate system" isn't an error, just a warning. If you pull up the properties, you'll probably see that it has coordinate values assigned.

Comment: Maybe this will help:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/121357/175465 and this:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316762/175465

Comment: World file (.pgw, .tfw etc) defines the relation between pixel coordinates and real-world coordinates https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/world-files-for-raster-datasets.htm, but it does not tell what is the coordinate system of the real world coordinates. The coordinate system can be saved into a .prj file. It is not mandatory to have the .prj file and if it is missing then user just needs to know what is the correct coordinate system and define it manually.